# robot framework with java keywords : Selenium.open(..) opens Firefox browser in hidden mode

Tags: java, firefox, keyword, selenium-rc, robotframework

I have a Java test automation suite developed with selenium RC. Trying to call Java methods in Robot Framework test suite as keywords.

At times, I see that Selenium.open(..) , though gets executed, Firefox browser (version 38.3) is hidden, and next command can not find the launched Window, though Robot test report says open command is successful.

Same code works fine with Google Chrome.

So how do we unhide the Hidden FF Window:

Code:

### Java

```
public class UILib{
  public void initSelenium(){
    Selenium selenium=new DefaultSelenium(SEL_HOST, SEL_PORT, "chrome", ADMURL);
    //Starting Selenium Instance
    selenium.start();

    //Opening Selenium Browser
    selenium.open(AdminURL);
    Thread.sleep(1000);

  } 
}
```

### Robot Test Suite

```
*** Settings ***
Library    somepackage.UILib

*** Test Cases ***
Open Login page
     Init Selenium
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get to the root cause of this issue yet. Though I could make it work by upgrading FF version to 38.5.1 .

Answer (score 0):

To maximise your browser window use this:

```
//Opening Selenium Browser
selenium.open(AdminURL);
selenium.windowMaximize()
```

Comment: It does not work. As the Firefox window is hidden, and not visible, though the commands get executed, effect can't be seen. Thanks.

Comment: @VivekKulkarni Ok, what exactly do you mean with "hidden"? I can only think of "minimized" or "headless". But the latter is bound to your X server and would affect Chrome, too.

Comment: Hidden is, browser does not visible at all, but in task manager process list, browser is listed. And all Selenium-Window methods execute successfully on that browser session, though nothing is visible. Hope this clears. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Robot Framework Builtin command for maximizing the browser.

```
Maximize Browser Window
```

Comment: This will not work, as selenium session is initiated by the Java class, and 'Maximize Browser Window' works only on session initiated by Robot framework. Thanks.